# Is it possible to use windows rdp to automatically running scripts

Tags: windows, rdp

I need to run a script on a large number of windows VMs. psremoting or WMI remoting would be ideal for this, but those connections are blocked by the firewall. However the firewall does enable RDP connections.

It would be possible to remote desktop to each VM individually and run the script, but I want to automate this. Is there anyway to do so through RDP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If this helps you, But if you are using Hyper-V and you have admin access to   Hyper-V host, you could try PowerShell Direct :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-windows-virtual-machines-with-powershell-direct